I'm trying to build a game for Android but the following error occurs
I'm trying to build a game for Android but the following error occurs:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
Has anyone encountered this?
I just tweaked the settings in Player Settings, nothing more.
